# On Server parachain sudden stopped producing block

Tags: parachain

Polkadot version i am using is: V0.9.36.
I am running the parachain with local environment on server.
The parachain sudden stopping producing the blocks.
I have looked at the logs but not get any leads from there.[image]

[image]

Comment: Your parachain log shows 0 peers. Do you only have 1 node?

Comment: Yeah. On server we run like we run in local environment so its with single parachain node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general for local test, we can use Developer-Sudo `slots.forceLease` on rococo-local to force lease slots for your local parachain.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check your parachain's slot lease. Maybe it gets downgraded.

This is pretty common if you are using Rococo local.

[image]
[image]

Check these to see if you are a parathread.

If you are, then you should call this to onboard you.

[image]

Comment: Any guide/resource how can i launch it to my server?

Comment: I updated my answer.